# Metatrader5 login() Python script not working

Tags: python, metatrader4, metatrader5

Currently following this tutorial to connect Python to Metatrader5:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu2q28h9Uvc

I am already stuck at 1:45 where my Metatrader5 initializes correctly, it opens but doesn't login with the credentials entered in my script. I use a broker Demo account. When I login manually, it works. I don't see an error or anything. If I login manually, I am able to print out my account info via my script, so connection somehow seems ok.. It drives me crazy that such a simple thing is not working, I am not getting any errors..

This is my script:

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime


server = "ICMarketsSC-Demo"
login = myaccountid
password = "mypassword"

mt.initialize()
mt.login(login, password, server)

account_info = mt.account_info()
print(account_info)
```

Documentation referance:
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5login_py

Please let me know if you see what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the current arguments you you giving to the login function to the initialize function, and only pass the login and password to login().

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime


server = "ICMarketsSC-Demo"
login = myaccountid
password = "mypassword"

mt5.initialize(login, password, server)
mt5.login(login, password)

account_info = mt5.account_info()
print(account_info)
```